# Getting a file name after being loaded into Google Colab

Tags: python, upload, filenames, google-colaboratory

What I want: to get the file name of the file that was just uploaded into Google Colab via the following code.

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

I tried: printing the file once I uploaded it and I get the following output.

```
print(uploaded)
{'2019.06.01_Short Maintenance - Vehicle, Malibu_TGZ.csv': b'Year,Miles,$/Gallon,Total $,Vehicle\r\n6/1/2019,343.4,2.529,28,Malibu\r\n6/8/2019,34.3,2.529,5,Malibu\r\n6/8/2019,315.6,2.529,33.1,Malibu\r\n6/30/2019,323,2.399,30,Malibu\r\n7/5/2019,316.4,2.559,31,Malibu\r\n7/12/2019,334.6,2.529,30.45,Malibu\r\n7/21/2019,288.7,2.459,33.75,Malibu\r\n7/29/2019,336.7,2.419,28,Malibu\r\n8/6/2019,317.3,2.379,30.45,Malibu\r\n8/14/2019,340.9,2.359,30.1,Malibu\r\n8/22/2019,307.4,2.299,29.85,Malibu\r\n9/1/2019,239.1,2.279,29.7,Malibu\r\n9/14/2019,237.8,2.419,28.9,Malibu\r\n9/6/2019,288,2.469,30.4,Malibu\r\n10/13/2019,305.7,2.299,27.81,Malibu\r\n10/20/2019,330.7,2.369,30.05,Malibu\r\n11/8/2019,257,2.429,32.4,Malibu\r\n12/3/2019,249.3,2.319,5.01,Malibu\r\n12/7/2019,37.2,2.099,25,Malibu\r\n12/22/2019,276.4,2.229,29.4,Malibu\r\n1/12/2020,334,2.199,5,Malibu\r\n1/19/2020,51,2.009,28.15,Malibu\r\n2/8/2020,231.5,2.079,25.8,Malibu\r\n2/23/2020,254.7,2.159,25.75,Malibu\r\n3/19/2020,235.3,1.879,23.15,Malibu\r\n5/22/2020,303,1.699,23.15,Malibu\r\n'}
```

It appears to be a dic with the key as the file name, and value as a string of all the data in the file. I don't know how to ge the key value, assuming that is what I need to do.

Answer (score 5):

It's in the keys of uploaded. You can use iter() and next() to get it.

```
filename = next(iter(uploaded))
```

Comment: When there exists a file with the same name, the uploaded filename will change (output will be something like this: "Saving filename.txt to filename (1).txt"), but this command returns the original filename: filename.txt and this will cause error in loading the file using this variable

Answer (score 0):

Access by getting keys

```
filenames = uploaded.keys()

for file in filenames:
    data = uploaded[file]
```

If you have more than one file, just create a list for your data and append retrieved values.